# Will update_attributes release lock in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Code

```
@abc = Abc.find(1,:lock => true)
@abc.update_attributes!(:title => "ABC title")
```

update_attributes will release a lock or not ? OR only @abc.save! will release a lock ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1267
def update_attributes(attributes)
  load(attributes) && save
end
```

So if save releases a lock, then update_attributes will do the same.